# Incorporating 7z in macrodef in ANT

Tags: ant, macrodef

I have been using a macro definition to copy a set of files to different locations and FTP servers. But copying seems quite slow so I want to compress the bundle using 7z and copy all into FTP as one single file. Can it be done using 7z? My amcrodef is below which works:

```
<macrodef name="copyimages">
  <attribute name="todir"/>
  <sequential>
    <copy todir="@{todir}" overwrite="true" failonerror="false">
      <fileset dir="${build.output.dir}">
                  <include name="logs/*${build.id}*armv5*scan2.html"/>
                  <include name="logs/*${build.id}*main.ant.log"/>
        <include name="logs/*${build.id}*bom.xml"/>
        <include name="logs/compile/*${build.id}*.*"/>
        <include name="logs/cone/*${build.id}*.*"/>
        <include name="logs/post/*${build.id}*.*"/>
        <include name="logs/roms/*${build.id}*.*"/>
        <include name="**/*${build.id}_codescanner/**"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </sequential>
</macrodef>


<copyimages todir="${publish.ssdoci.dir}/${env.version}.${build.number}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not particular about `7z`, then you can use the [Zip Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html).

You could try something like this instead of `<copy></copy`...

```
<zip destfile ="@{destfile}">
  <fileset dir="${build.output.dir}">
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*armv5*scan2.html"/>
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*main.ant.log"/>
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*bom.xml"/>
    <include name="logs/compile/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/cone/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/post/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/roms/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="**/*${build.id}_codescanner/**"/>
  </fileset>
</zip>

<copyimages destfile="${publish.ssdoci.file}-${env.version}.${build.number}"/>
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the ZIP syntax that could work with the macro above?

Comment: @user579910. Updated answer with example syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is no task for 7zip - and <zip> cannot archive with password.
My solution is therefore

```
<target name="zip" depends="dist">
    <exec executable="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe">
        <arg value="a" />                         <!--archive-->
        <arg value="-pMyPasswordt" />             <!-- password -->
        <arg value="-r" />                        <!-- recursiv -->
        <arg value="C:\temp\2012-06-29\${programName}.zip" />  <!-- destination -->
        <arg value="${jarFile}" />                <!-- files to archive -->
    </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [apache.org](http://ant.apache.org/antlibs/compress/)  there is support for 7z.
From [osdir.com](http://osdir.com/ml/notifications-ant-apache/2013-10/msg00035.html) there are comments on implementing `sevenz` task that works the same way you would use zip

Using maven ?

```
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

In ant

```
<taskdef resource="org/apache/ant/compress/antlib.xml" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
<sevenz destfile ="my.7z">
  <fileset dir="${build.output.dir}">
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*armv5*scan2.html"/>
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*main.ant.log"/>
    <include name="logs/*${build.id}*bom.xml"/>
    <include name="logs/compile/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/cone/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/post/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="logs/roms/*${build.id}*.*"/>
    <include name="**/*${build.id}_codescanner/**"/>
  </fileset>
</sevenz>
<un7z src="my.7z" dest="unpack" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using 7z.exe with "exec" is the best option.

Here is the syntax:

**C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe a -t7z c:\temp\test.7z c:\temp*.txt**

*this command put all .txt file from c:\temp to archive "test.7z"

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

There is a 7z ant task available here: http://www.pharmasoft.be/7z/

Did not test it, though, and the site seems already a little dated.